# Add-Ons in view only and comment mode?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been looking everywhere and I can't for the life of me find any info on this.

So I've published a workflow add-on internally for my company, and I've just now realized that there is no add-on menu in view only mode on documents, and in suggest mode the menu is there, but empty.

Is there any way to enable my add-on in these states?  As it is critical to the functionality of my scripts.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use a Google Site, with a two column design.  Doc on left side, Apps Script HTML App in a Apps Script gadget on the right?  I haven't tried it, so it might be a stupid idea or not work for you.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea! It's not originally what I was going for and would require a large rework, but it is an interesting idea that I will definitely give some thought.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not possible. add-ons (and any apps script in general) requires write permission to the bound document.

i cant find it anywhere in the official docs either, thou its vaguely suggested in the docs by saying "collaborators" https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle

i know its not supported because it was the first question i asked google a year ago when the feature was introduced. they said no so i never built my addon either because it was needed by my would-be addon.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was afraid this was the case.  
Looks like its time to implement yet another workaround!..  Really wish apps script wasn't so restricting.